# python permutations, including duplicates

Tags: python, permutation

I have created a program that determines when the surface area of a cuboid is the same as the area.

```
from itertools import permutations

def area(l, h, w):
    return(l*h*w)

def surf_area(l, h, w):
    return(((l*h)+(l*w)+(w*h))*2)

for length, height, width in permutations(range(1,100),3):
    if area(length, height, width)== surf_area(length, height, width):
        print("length = {}, height = {}, width = {}".format(length,height,width))
```

This iterates through the numbers 1-100 and puts them as the height length and width of the cuboid and only returns the answers which have the same area and surface area

This yields:

```
length = 3, height = 7, width = 42
length = 3, height = 8, width = 24
length = 3, height = 9, width = 18
length = 3, height = 10, width = 15
length = 3, height = 15, width = 10
length = 3, height = 18, width = 9
length = 3, height = 24, width = 8
length = 3, height = 42, width = 7
length = 4, height = 5, width = 20
length = 4, height = 6, width = 12
length = 4, height = 12, width = 6
length = 4, height = 20, width = 5
length = 5, height = 4, width = 20
length = 5, height = 20, width = 4
length = 6, height = 4, width = 12
length = 6, height = 12, width = 4
length = 7, height = 3, width = 42
length = 7, height = 42, width = 3
length = 8, height = 3, width = 24
length = 8, height = 24, width = 3
length = 9, height = 3, width = 18
length = 9, height = 18, width = 3
length = 10, height = 3, width = 15
length = 10, height = 15, width = 3
length = 12, height = 4, width = 6
length = 12, height = 6, width = 4
length = 15, height = 3, width = 10
length = 15, height = 10, width = 3
length = 18, height = 3, width = 9
length = 18, height = 9, width = 3
length = 20, height = 4, width = 5
length = 20, height = 5, width = 4
length = 24, height = 3, width = 8
length = 24, height = 8, width = 3
length = 42, height = 3, width = 7
length = 42, height = 7, width = 3
```

Now, if you look closely, none of the measurements are ever the same e.g. I would never get the answer (not correct answer)

```
length = 3, height = 3, width = 3
```

as it only iterates through the numbers once. How can I include these "doubled" answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead of `permutations`:

```
for l, w, h in itertools.product(range(1, 100), repeat=3):
```

This will exhaustively go through all possible combinations of three numbers from `1`-`99`, including cases where `l == w == h`.

A smaller example:

```
>>> for l, w, h in itertools.product(range(1, 3), repeat=3):
    print(l, w, h)


(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Or if the order shouldn't matter, you could use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 100), 3)`, also this could be more clearly written as `itertools.product(range(1, 100), repeat=3)`.

Comment: why did you place a product sign behind *[range(1,3)]

Comment: @user3727754 to unpack the list of three `range` objects as three separate arguments to `product` - see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: @AndrewClark the OPs results included 3x7x42 and 3x42x7 etc, so I assumed they wanted all versions. Good point on the keyword argument to `product`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this answer really is brilliant and answered my question but is very slow to calculate

Comment: @moishinetzer doesn't take long here, I get 46 solutions immediately. What range are you using? Also, what do you think area (actually volume) and surface area are? 3,3,3 isn't a valid solution.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i am using `range(1,100)`. surface area is the area of all the surfaces added together. and i clearly wrote: " I would never get the answer **(not correct answer)**"

Comment: @moishinetzer ah, sorry. But I still have no performance issues for `range(1, 100)`, I get the answers immediately.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you very much anyways i really appreciate it